# UI for changing floors on a building's map in Android

Tags: android, maps

I have an app that shows the map for a floor inside a building. Now there should be a function to change floors (go up/down or show an overview of the floors). I have put buttons to go up or down in the Action Bar but it doesn't feel right.

I am really lacking creativity and can not find a proper UI design that fits within the Android Design Guidelines.

I don't want to step away from the Android Design Guidelines.

I would appreciate it if anyone could give me a nice Android design pattern that I could use for this purpose. The more suggestions the better!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Google Map's floor navigator? This is an interface that has millions of global users:

[image]

You may also want to look up BIM or Building Information Management software.  There is a lot of work going into BIM interfaces to navigate 3D building models.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the Google Design Guidelines overhere:
http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html#tabs-content

You can find Tabs, this could be a solution when you have a tab for all floors, and then tabs for floor 1, floor 2, etc. Though, I hope it is not for a sky scraper. In addition, if you want to stick to the Google Design Guidelines you cannot use tabs in tabs, so it also depends on what the content of your page is exactly.

It would be convenient if you showed a mockup or screenshot of what you have now to clarify your situation a little.

Another solution could be a slider to go up a level, and keep it kind of the same as the zoom slider in Google Maps?